# how to get checked values from angular selected material table

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular5

How to fetch selected rows from a mat-table selection

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aqeokxeyokv?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47051485/7124761

Comment: @PrashantPimpale thank you, but how to get array of items checked ..

Comment: Bind the value with ngmodule

Comment: This will give a collection of objecta

Answer (score 14):

You can get the *`selected`* or *`checked`* item of Material Selection Table by using:

```
this.selection.selected
```

this will gives you the checked items from the table.

<kbd>[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlk4vf)</kbd>

Comment: Hello, after retreiving the checked items, how can I uncheck items? For example, i am trying to avoid items from being checked after 15 items, but when i reach the item number 15 i can prevent from being added to the list, but i cannot avoid the check on that item, how can i avoid items from being checked after the item number 15?

Comment: @Jonny give me some time, will check it

Comment: @Jonny Can you show me the code? Or Stackblitz example so I can check there

Comment: Thanks for your response, i already did it, but now i have the problem that i cannot retrieve the selected items when i return and load them from the backend, the list keep showing that none is selected.