# Angular Material table row (click) event triggered when clicking an action in a cell within that row

Tags: angular, angular-material, bootstrap-modal, angular-cdk, onrowclick

How can you trigger a modal with a button inside a mat-table without triggering the rows (click) event? I've seen and read with [Angular Material 2 Table Mat Row Click event also called with button click in Mat Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051485/angular-material-2-table-mat-row-click-event-also-called-with-button-click-in-ma?rq=1) however the solution of using $event.stopPropagation() there prevents the modal from being displayed.

I followed this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting?file=app%2Ftable-example.html for the row expansion functionality.

Here's a small snippet of my code:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Username</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.username}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="email" class="hideOnResponse">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.email}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <a (click)="editItem(element)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editor" matTooltip="Edit" aria-label="tooltip">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
              </a>
              <a (click)="deleteItem(element.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editor" matTooltip="Delete" aria-label="tooltip">
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
              </a>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="element-row" [ccDetailRow]="row" [ccDetailRowTpl]="tpl"></mat-row>
        <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide':dataSource!=null}"></mat-footer-row>
        <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(dataSource!=null && dataSource.data.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
      </mat-table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]="5" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

I've tried doing what was stated on the question linked above but to no avail. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got answer from here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051485/angular-material-2-table-mat-row-click-event-also-called-with-button-click-in-ma)

As Will says:

> Try adding $event.stopPropagation() to one of the deeper click
>   handlers (like on the cell).

try doing something similar to this:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let group" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <button mat-button (click)="onDelete(group.id)">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-cell>
```

**in your case If I'm correct it would be:**

```
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          <a (click)="editItem(element)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editor" matTooltip="Edit" aria-label="tooltip">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
          </a>
          <a (click)="deleteItem(element.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editor" matTooltip="Delete" aria-label="tooltip">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
          </a>
      </mat-cell>
```

What I had before was that I had edit and delete button in expanded view. I put them in the normal view and added stopPropagation. It worked for me. I am not sure why your modal isn't being open.

here's code from my project:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="recordDate">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Record Date </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let request" (click)=$event.stopPropagation()> {{request.recDate | date }} 
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon" (click)="openDialog(true, request.requestId)">edit</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon" (click)="deleteRequest(request.requestId)">delete</mat-icon>
  </button>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it disables the modal from being displayed.

Comment: oh my bad. didn't notice it in your question.

Comment: I am exactly the same expandable table and I have edit and delete buttons too. The only difference is that my buttons appear on expanded version of the row. So I don't get the problem. That might not be what you want, but it might be a temporary solution