# Angular Material Table Firefox Mat Row Click event with button click in Mat Cell

Tags: firefox, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-table, onrowclick

I want to use the angular material mat-table with clickable rows and also a button column **with Firefox Browser**.

When i first added the button the event was not triggered (just the event of the row).

I read some threads about that issue:
[Angular Material 2 Table Mat Row Click event also called with button click in Mat Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051485/angular-material-2-table-mat-row-click-event-also-called-with-button-click-in-ma)

[Angular Material table row (click) event triggered when clicking an action in a cell within that row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407774/angular-material-table-row-click-event-triggered-when-clicking-an-action-in-a)

I got it working with `event.stopPropagation` on the Chrome Browser but not on Firefox 63.0.3 (64-Bit). No Event is triggered at all in Firefox.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
.
.
.
  <ng-container *ngIf="roles.approver" matColumnDef="approve">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Approve</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
      <button mat-icon-button type="button">
        <mat-icon color="primary" (click)="approve(element.receipt_id, 2)">check_circle</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="onDetail(row.receipt_id)"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Anyone got it working with Firefox?