# Mat Table Expandable Rows Angular 7

Tags: angular, expandable, mat-table

Is there way to disable row expansion on a specific column. Generally if you click on any part of a row the it expands. But say one column is a comment section, you wouldn't want the row to expand when the user clicks in the input field. 
Like in this example. How do you prevent the row from expanding when clicking on say the position column: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gqvrlgbeqkv?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Angular Material or other Design components for Angular if you search more.

See this for example: [Expansion Panel | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)

**Update:** you can try use `$event.stopPropagation` as said in this solution: [Angular Material 2 Table Mat Row Click event also called with button click in Mat Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051485/angular-material-2-table-mat-row-click-event-also-called-with-button-click-in-ma?rq=1)

Comment: I'm talking about something like in this example. How do you prevent the row from expanding when clicking on say the position column: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gqvrlgbeqkv?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

Comment: @Flash so you want it to expand if you click on name,weight and symbol columns and not if clicked on position column?

Comment: right because in my case that column would be a comment section and I don't want it to expand every time they click on the input field

Comment: @Flash Then you can try use `$event.stopPropagation` as said in this solution: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051485/angular-material-2-table-mat-row-click-event-also-called-with-button-click-in-ma?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

In your example Stackblitz the code which expands a row is set on the row definition:

```
...
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
  class="example-element-row"
  [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
  (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
</tr>
...
```

In order to have the row only expand if the user clicks on a specific column (or in your case not to expand if a specific column is clicked) you need to move the onClick function and the necessary css to those columns which should expand, e.g.

```
    ...
    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="example-element-row" [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
         (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    ...
```

I've modified your example to not expand/collapse if the position column is clicked: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbbxls)

PS: for better maintainability you should adjust the css class names etc.

Comment: Thanks the $event.stopPropagation was a quicker solution

Answer (score 1):

Use pointer events none

> The pointer-events property defines whether or not an element reacts
>   to pointer events.

create a Class with pointer-events: none property then use ngClass to add dynamically

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
        [class.disable]="element[column] == 'Hydrogen' || element[column] == '1.0079' 
        || element[column] == 1 ||element[column] == 'H'">  {{element[column]}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpp7fx

Comment: In that example the whole first row is just disabled from expanding

Comment: you can enable the column by removing the conditions